# django-auth-ldap AUTH_LDAP_FIND_GROUPS_PERMS not working

Tags: python, django, ldap, django-auth-ldap

I'm running Django 1.8.18 and django-auth-ldap 1.2.11 authenticating against Active Directory.

My current configuration authenticates properly against the AD, however, when I enabled `AUTH_LDAP_FIND_GROUPS_PERMS` it doesn't seem to do anything. I've previously tried `AUTH_LDAP_MIRROR_GROUPS` (which works without any problem), and found all of the user's groups created. The only slight issue is that it also remove any local group memberships the user had.

In any case, after having the groups auto-created by `AUTH_LDAP_MIRROR_GROUPS` I would expect `AUTH_LDAP_FIND_GROUPS_PERMS` would auto-add the user to that same group on the next login. However, this did not happen. The only change in configuration was those two lines. The `AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_TYPE` is set to `NestedActiveDirectoryGroupType()`

Any ideas why users aren't being added to the groups with matching names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that `AUTH_LDAP_FIND_GROUPS_PERMS` doesn't actually add users to a group, but virtually adds them to it making sure their permissions respond as if they are in the groups that match names.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was really confusing to debug, because the only way to verify that things worked was not the intuitive way of looking whether the _group membership_ has been established, but the indirect way of looking whether the _permissions have been granted_.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that it's the `AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_TYPE` you're using. I am also using this library, and have it syncing groups/memberships. This is a full dump of my settings for the library:

```
AUTH_LDAP_START_TLS = True
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = 'xxxx'
AUTH_LDAP_GLOBAL_OPTIONS = {
    ldap.OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT: ldap.OPT_X_TLS_NEVER
}
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = 'yyyy'
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = 'zzzz'
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearchUnion(
    LDAPSearch(
        'OU=OurCorp,DC=foo,DC=bar,DC=com',
        ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
        filterstr='(uid=%(user)s)'
    ),
)

AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {
    "first_name": "givenName",
    "last_name": "sn",
    "email": "mail",
}

AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_TYPE = ActiveDirectoryGroupType()
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_SEARCH = LDAPSearch(
    'OU=Security Groups,OU=Users and Groups,OU=OurCorp,DC=foo,DC=bar,DC=com',
    ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
    '(objectClass=group)'
)
AUTH_LDAP_MIRROR_GROUPS = True

AUTH_LDAP_USER_FLAGS_BY_GROUP = {
    'is_staff': [  # Allow login to the Django admin site
        'CN=Our-Staff-Group,OU=Security Groups,OU=Users and Groups,OU=OurCorp,DC=foo,DC=bar,DC=com',
    ],
    'is_superuser': [  # Implicitly grant ALL permissions to members of these groups
        'CN=Our-Superuser-Group,OU=Security Groups,OU=Users and Groups,OU=OurCorp,DC=foo,DC=bar,DC=com'
    ],
}
```

As I mentioned, I think the `AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_TYPE` is likely your issue, but that could depend on your own AD setup.

Comment: Ah, I figured it out - I assumed that `AUTH_LDAP_FIND_GROUPS_PERMS` would add the user to the groups in question. Instead, it simply creates a virtual membership in the group responding to permission checks in line with the group.

Comment: I fell upon the same issue and your solution really worked. Thank you :-)